# NULL Value on Attribute when reading XML in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

There are 3 attributes I am trying to return when reading this xml file. 2 of the 3 are returning expected values.  I can not figure out why I can't get the id to return the value. It always returns NULL. How can I get the proper value of rid1 and rid2

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SELECT @xml = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\data\workbook.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 
'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main' ,                    
'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships' as a,
'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006' as b,
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main' as c,                   
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac' as d)

SELECT
 doc.col.value('@name', 'nvarchar(10)') sheet
,doc.col.value('@id', 'nvarchar(max)') rid 
,doc.col.value('@sheetId', 'int') id 
FROM @xml.nodes('*:workbook/sheets/sheet') doc(col)
```

Here is the XML File

```
    <workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main" mc:Ignorable="x15">
  <fileVersion appName="xl" lastEdited="7" lowestEdited="7" rupBuild="18431" />
  <workbookPr defaultThemeVersion="166925" />
  <mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <mc:Choice Requires="x15">
      <x15ac:absPath xmlns:x15ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac" url="C:\data\" />
    </mc:Choice>
  </mc:AlternateContent>
  <bookViews>
    <workbookView xWindow="0" yWindow="0" windowWidth="21576" windowHeight="7968" />
  </bookViews>
  <sheets>
    <sheet name="Sheet1" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1" />
    <sheet name="Sheet2" sheetId="2" r:id="rId2" />
  </sheets>
  <calcPr calcId="171027" />
  <fileRecoveryPr repairLoad="1" />
  <extLst>
    <ext xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main" uri="{140A7094-0E35-4892-8432-C4D2E57EDEB5}">
      <x15:workbookPr chartTrackingRefBase="1" />
    </ext>
  </extLst>
</workbook>
```

[image: results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix the attribute with the namespace like so:

```
SELECT
 doc.col.value('@name', 'nvarchar(10)') sheet
,doc.col.value('@a:id', 'nvarchar(max)') rid 
,doc.col.value('@sheetId', 'int') id 
FROM @xml.nodes('*:workbook/sheets/sheet') doc(col)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your namespaces the same aliases in your T-SQL as they have in your XML and use the namespace alias in your reference:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main',
                    'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships' AS r,
                    'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006' AS mc,
                    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main' AS x15,
                    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac' AS x15ac)
SELECT doc.col.value('@name', 'nvarchar(10)') sheet,
       doc.col.value('@r:id', 'nvarchar(max)') rid,
       doc.col.value('@sheetId', 'int') id
FROM @xml.nodes('*:workbook/sheets/sheet') doc(col);
```

Comment: Not making a comment on proper form, but you don't have to make them the same alias as XML doc.  I had like you suggest initially, but then changed during debug process to see if my namespace was not proper. The name space declaration was not the issue is was not prefixing @id.  I like the way your code looks, so +1

Comment: @Timberline411 You don't have to, no, but it does help. :)